# ":focus" pseudoclass is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, pseudo-class

I am using a :focus pseudo-class for my buttons (when pressed). It works fine on Firefox but it doesn't change its state in Chrome. Is there any workaround?

**CSS:**

```
.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #586601 inset;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000000;
}
```

(It's an input tag with a class "btn".)

Comment: Yes it can.. At it is working in Chrome: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPdkk/1/), click the textbox and then pres `Tab` key. What is meant by *when pressed*? How does it relate to focus?

Comment: @MichalKlouda I don't get any effect. Chrome22/Win7

Comment: @MichalKlouda. Oh - the button gets focus when tabbed to, but not when clicked.

Comment: Do you distinguish between focused and clicked button?

Comment: @MichalKlouda When clicked. In firefox, the :focus pseudoclass works on click. Now that I tried, the :focus style gets applied when I press "tab" on Chrome. But can it work on click too just like in Firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to distinguish between `:focus` and `:active`, see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

> The `:focus` selector is used to select the element that has focus.
>
> The `:active` selector is used to select and style the active link.
>
> A link becomes active when you click on it.

You should change your styles to:

```
.btn:active, .btn:focus {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #586601 inset;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000000;
}
```

> Note: `:active` MUST come after `:hover` (if present) in the CSS
>   definition in order to be effective!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RPdkk/2/)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that since it behaved differently in Firefox. Thanks a lot. ;) It's now working.

Comment: `:active` only applies the style during the click, then removes it: http://jsfiddle.net/HSWDc/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want a button to get focus when clicked (chrome apparently doesn't do that for you), you can do it manually. Using jQuery:

```
$(".btn").on("click",function(){
  $(this).focus()
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSWDc/

Comment: Chrome did focus it for me, but Firefox didn't (using pure css). With Chrome the focus works on buttons and with Firefox it works on anchors. Your solution did the trick for me, now working in both browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #586601 inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #586601 inset;
-webkit-text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000000;
-moz-text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000000;
```